# Question Regarding Design Constraints in Software Engineering Exam

Tags: software-engineering

I recently had a software engineering exam, and there's a particular question that's causing some confusion between my professor and me. I'd like to get some insights from the community to better understand this issue. If I can convince my professor I was right, I could get a higher grade.

The Question:

The question in the exam was as follows:

"The design constraints imposed on the sorting system are:

a. Programming language and algorithms

b. Security and system interaction

c. Platform and schedule

d. Usability and performance"

In our textbook, "Essentials of Software Engineering" by Frank F. Tsui, it states that: " The thinking process related to design constraints can be summarized as follows:

User-interface
Typical and maximum input sizes
Platforms
Schedule requirements "
And my professor said that the correct answer is c), based on this section of the book.

Then the book goes:

"The steps and thoughts related to design decisions for the sorting problem can be summarized as follows:

Programming language: Typically this will be a technical design decision, although it is not uncommon to be given as a design constraint.

Algorithms : ... Algorithms are usually design decisions, but they can be given as design constraints or even considered functional requirements. "

My professor marked my answer as incorrect and insisted that the correct answer is "c. Platform and schedule." However, my perspective is that "a. Programming language and algorithms" is a valid choice as well, based on the information from our textbook. His response was : "Design constraints (limit) and design decisions (decisions) are two different ones which are different in chapters 1.1.4 and 1.1.5 respectively. The question on the test was about design constraints, and programming language and algorithms are design decisions."

I've discussed this with my professor, but we couldn't come to an agreement. I believe that the textbook's explanation supports my answer.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide their insights on this matter. Am I interpreting the book correctly? Is "Programming language and algorithms" a valid choice as design constraints based on the provided book excerpt? If so, how can I approach this situation with my professor to clarify my perspective?

I want to ensure that I have a clear understanding of the material and the exam evaluation. Your input would be valuable in resolving this issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

[image: Design Constraints]
[image: Sorting problem]

Comment: Please don't [crosspost](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/447436/question-regarding-design-constraints-in-software-engineering-exam), When you are going to move a question from one SE site to another one, please delete the first post *before* you ask on the second. Note also this question will be here note less opinion based than it was on [swe.se]

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the answer is "all of the above".

- Programming language and algorithms: is it worth the cost of a new compiler and associated tools to use the newest wiz-bang language, or do you make do with the language and tools you have already purchased?  What algorithms will allow the application to perform in a timely manner?
- Security and system interaction: does the computer that runs the application have enough resources (both compute power for security and external interfaces for system interaction) to successfully perform the job.
- Platform and Schedule: does a development system need to be purchased to run on the proposed platform, does the proposed platform have the resources to successfully run the application?  Can the project be completed within the scheduled time frame?
- Usability and Performance: big time constraint here, if your application runs too slow or has a terrible user interface, it will never sell.